# Android getItem in FragmentPagerAdapter unable to return FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to return a FragmentActivity from getItem(int index) in a FragmentPagerAdapter.   I'm using the FragmentActivity to implement a listview in a tab.  Is there any work around for this?

```
@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return null; //new GamesFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return null;//new MoviesFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the getitem() mth documentation on developer, it is not apssoble to retuen FragmentActivity.

```
abstract Fragment getItem(int position)
Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
```

Answer (score 0):

FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem() method does not and cannot return a FragmentActivity. FragmentPagerAdapter's main purpose in life is to manage the various pages in ViewPager. To show a ListView in a ViewPager tab, you can extend FragmentPagerAdapter as follows:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> mPages;

    public MyCustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> viewPagerPageItems) {
        super(fm);
        mPages = viewPagerPageItems;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPages.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int viewPagerTabPosition) {
        switch (viewPagerTabPosition) {
           case 0:
              // this fragment should extend ListFragment, where you could call 
              // getListView() in the onCreate() or onActivityCreated() method.
              // to inflate your list
              return TopRatedListFragment.newInstance(mPages.get(position));
           case 1:

           case 2:
               break;
    }

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

The ListFragment structure and the newInstance() factory method follows the approach described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).